# Is the sentence proper English?

Tags: grammar

For many people, it is economical to flush the toilet by the water collected from showering.

Does this sentence sound like proper English? If not, how do you make it better?

Comment: What do you think Delfino? Can you think of a way to improve it?

Comment: It's grammatical but not very idiomatic. Presumably it _would_ be economical for everyone to do so _if_ they had a system set up to enable them to do so.

Comment: To me, it would seem more natural as "with water collected from the shower".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you should write '**using water**' instead of '**by water**'. For instance,

> For many people, it is economical to flush the toilet using the water collected from showering.

Also, you can use 'shower water' instead of '**water collected from showering**'.

> For many people, it is economical to flush the toilet using shower water.

You can also delete '**For many people**' since the action is economical (save water) for *almost* everyone.

> Using shower water to flush the toilet is economical.

However, you should retain the words if you want to include persons who don't shower at all in which case using shower water to flush the toilet will not be economical for them.